# How to average multiple lists of various lengths?

Tags: python

I am trying to average numbers of different lists of varying lengths. (in nested-list form as shown below)

```
mylist =[[1, 3, 7, 10], [3, 9, 9, 0], [5, 6]]
```

I want the result of

```
averaged_list = [3, 6, 8, 5]
```

I have tried,

```
averaged_list = [mean(x) for x in zip(*mylist)]
```

which only lends:

```
[3, 6]
```

*mylist* above is simplified just to demonstrate the purpose but it will be lengthier in practice.
Thank you for the help and advice!

Comment: `[mean(x) for x in mylist]`

Comment: @ThePyGuy nope, this is not what OP asks.

Comment: @Julien, oh yeah, I didn't look at expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will ignore excess values according to the shortest length iterable. You must use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead, and must take care of filtering the `None` fill-values:

```python
import itertools

averaged_list = [
    mean((x for x in xs if x is not None))  # ignore fillvalues
    for xs in itertools.zip_longest(*mylist)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import numpy as np
averaged_list = [np.nanmean(x) for x in zip_longest(*mylist, fillvalue=np.nan)]
```

(See @michaeldel's answer for explanation, same idea)